# suppress column and remove blank space in crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2003.

I'm searching for a way to suppress a column if it is empty and replace the blank space left by the other columns.

I'm searching everywhere but I can't find a compatible way to the version 2003.

Does exist a simple way?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crystal Reports doesn't have an automatic (or easy) way to dynamically move columns.

You might consider multiple header and details sections that could approximate this--simply suppress the sections that contain the fields with NULL values.

Comment: I do believe in that.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the report object and select Format Field. On the Format screen -> Number tab click the Customize button. On the Custom Style screen -> Number Tab check the "Suppress If Zero" box.

But i don't think it can exist in version 2003

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the field click on Format Object next go to Common Tab -> there you will see Suppress Check box (check that checkbox) next to that there is Formula Editor icon click on that next write formula

```
if isnull({FieldName} ) then 
true 
else
false
```

Comment: it make sense but it didn't work for me.. But thank you anyway

Comment: this solution will work, just put in the formula isnull({FieldName} ), and remove check on suppress check box.

Comment: I did a little modification and it worked.
if (Vel({FieldName}) = 0) then ... (The rest). 
But I still need to know if i can fill the space with the next column, coz I don't want to keep the field blank..

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I was having this issue for a completely separate reason. 
I had multiple groups in the report, one of which was a Document Date. Right-clicking the group and going to Group Options, the "Keep Group Together" option was checked. This meant when there were multiple dates they would get moved to a second page and leave a large white space on page 1.

The white space depended on the result set returned by the query; sometimes it showed up, sometimes not, depending on how many records there were with the same date. 
Spent a good 2 hours trying to figure that out.

"Keep Together" in the Section expert for the group was UNCHECKED and I didn't even realize there was a "Keep Group Together" option until I stumbled upon it.

Answer (score 0):

I found difficulty in suppressing column name if its field value is null in crystal report in Visual Studio 2008. I write the code `({tableName.FiledName})="".`

It is very simple. Just right click the column name, choose format object, then a window will open. In the common tab, check the suppress check box. Click the x-2 icon beside suppress check box, then a format formula editor will open, write the code `({tableName.FiledName})=""`  then save and exit. If you make error, the editor will popup the message of error. you would notice that column name will be dimmed or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Follow *steps*:

1. Right Click on the field
2. Click on -> Format Object
3. Next go to Common Tab ->
4. There you will see Suppress Check box (check that checkbox) ->
5. Next to that there is Formula Editor icon click on that next write formula
   `IIF(isnull({datasetName.column_name}), True, False)`

its work fine but can't hide column empty space I think its difficult