# Select or Deselect Report Columns in Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

i want to build a payroll report that user can select or deselect columns as user wanted. for example for each employee user can select check boxes that represent each column in a list like - Nic, Net salary , Nopay day , etc in any combination.i think all columns are returned in the SP and only shows selected columns.Can you please give me some idea how to do it..

Comment: You can suppress each column (and header) in the report based on these parameters, but I don't think you can then shift your remaining columns to sit together. I tackled this problem a couple of years ago and ended up making a new presentation app that allowed this level of customization because I couldn't figure out how to adjust the layout of the report at runtime.

Comment: is there any presentation app that i can get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tilan. I'm not aware of a crystal reports presentation app that you can get that will make your job any easier, but I'd not be surprised if you are spoilt for choice. SAP offer report serving software and their material on Dashboard Design and Crystal Server may be worth looking at ([SAP Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/)). However, this may be overkill for your purposes.

An alternative approach is to try to define "loose" columns (I don't know the professional term!). I distinctly recall pulling this off some years ago, but don't recall the specifics and no longer have access to the report (previous employer). [This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/uditsingh/CR1111022006055359AM/CR11.aspx) covers the steps. It's ugly and has a range of disadvantages (huge gaps where columns have been suppressed being a big one), but it might solve your problem.

[This guy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20670/Dynamic-Crystal-Report-with-C) creates generic columns in his report then builds his query on the fly. His form only caters for the one report, but I think you could adapt his solution to suit your needs.

[Cross-tabs](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=181) may be exploited to suit your purposes (I think). I have little experience with these, but it seems a little tweaking might allow dynamic columns.

The better alternative (by far) is to handle this in your presentation. You've tagged WinForms and C#, so I can assume you've created a win app with a report viewer on it. Assuming you define your dataset in the report, your code should be able to handle the creation of columns at runtime (or suppress/enable and reposition) by looking at the report's DataDefinition. I've read that creating columns at runtime is somewhat dependent on your CR/VS version which I can only guess at.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the brief reply, i will try to workout your suggestions

Comment: if i can surpress columns based on check box value then above requirment can be implemented no?(Sp returns all the columns)

Comment: Yep, it _can_ be done that way, you'll just have big gaps in your output. Suppressing a column doesn't mean the column to the right of it will move to fill the newly emptied space. The article ("This guy") showing how to build your query on the fly and fit it to a generic layout will avoid that problem. How well it can be modified to suit your situation depends, at least in part, on the complexity of your query. Whether your stored procedure is used elsewhere is also a consideration.

Comment: i have about 35 columns will it be worth to write 35 sp's

Comment: It would have to be 35 SPs _and_ 35 reports. I'd say no, it's not worth it. Modify the table and you have 35 (x2) further modifications to make. There are more efficient and more economical ways to pull this off. I'm sorry to say that if those approaches I've suggested are beyond your grasp, you may have bitten off more than you can chew. [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15926265/2400222) suggests creating multiple header and details sections. I presume he means for each combination of columns. That, in your case, sounds as bad as creating 35 different SPs/reports!

Comment: i found this article is very useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28413/Custom-Field-in-Crystal-Report

Comment: Good find! This is essentially what I meant by "The better alternative (by far)". Something to be aware of, the author is looking for both the column header and the values in the same section, which doesn't seem right. Also keep in mind that this author assumes all fields are the same width.

Answer (score 0):

If you can narrow the combination of selected columns to a manageable minimum you can create a subreport for each combination and suppress all subreports except the right one.